# How to make child theme in wordpress with wp_enqueue_style ? Using Enough Theme

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I am using Enough theme and i want to create a child theme the way suggested in codex i.e. using wp_enqueue_style. I am doing it the way it's explained but left margin more now like it's indented to right. Seems to me some stylesheet loading problem.

I have created style.css and functions.php in child theme folder.
In parent theme folder there is 1 style.css file and 11 css file inside '/css' directory.

I have tried lot of things but not able to do it correctly. Below is how i am trying to load parent theme style sheets.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-options.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/colors.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/box-modules.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/approach.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/comment.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/layout-fluid.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/post-format.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ua.css' );
}
?>
```

I am using 'style' as first parameter because in the functions.php in parent theme i.i Enough i have following code, (I have put a line with arrow ------------> in front of the the code line) -

```
/**
 *
 *
 */
if ( !function_exists( "enough_enqueue_scripts_styles" ) ) {

    function enough_enqueue_scripts_styles() {

        global $is_IE, $enough_version;

        $enough_csses = array( "css/normalize.css", "genericons/genericons.css", "css/fonts.css", "css/box-modules.css", "css/comment.css", "css/ua.css", "css/colors.css", "css/base.css", "css/layout-fluid.css", "css/post-format.css", "css/approach.css" );

        foreach ( $enough_csses as $ecnough_css_path ) {

            if ( file_exists( trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . $ecnough_css_path ) ) {

                wp_enqueue_style( 'enough_' . basename( $ecnough_css_path, '.css' ), trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ) . $ecnough_css_path, array(), $enough_version );
            } else {

                wp_enqueue_style( 'enough_' . basename( $ecnough_css_path, '.css' ), trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . $ecnough_css_path, array(), $enough_version );
            }
        }

----------->wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'enough_approach' ), $enough_version );
        $gallery_style = enough_gallerys_css();
        wp_add_inline_style( 'styles', $gallery_style );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'enough-web-font', apply_filters( 'enough_web_font', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700' ) );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

        if ( $is_IE ) {

            wp_register_script( 'html5shiv', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/html5shiv.js', array(), '3', false );

            wp_enqueue_script( 'html5shiv' );
        }
    }

}
```

Do i need to create all css files in child themes ? or I can have only 1 css file namely style.css in child theme ? What would be the correct way of doing this ?

**Edited this way**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/admin-options.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/colors.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style4', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/box-modules.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style5', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/approach.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style6', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/comment.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style7', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style8', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/layout-fluid.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style9', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style10', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/post-format.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style11', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ua.css' );

}
?>
```

And here is **style.css** in child theme

```
/*
Theme Name: Enough Child
Theme URI: http://www.tenman.info/wp3/enough/
Description: Satisfied enough necessary minimum structure Responsive Theme. HTML5 , Supports Post Format Archives , You can select your favorite Post Format
Author: Tenman
Author URI: http://www.tenman.info/wp3/
Version: 1.22
Tags: two-columns,custom-colors, custom-header, custom-background, custom-menu, editor-style, threaded-comments, sticky-post, flexible-header
Template:     enough
Text Domain: enough-child
License: GNU General Public License v2.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
*/
```

The images _

[image: Parent Enough]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very best described in the WordPress [Child theme codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) page.

Basically to load child theme and parent theme stylesheet files, you have to just add following code in the functions.php file of your child theme.

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array( $parent_style, 'enough_base' ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 99 );
```

You don't need to enqueue other parent theme CSS files if you are not changing them.

Comment: I understand and i did that but there is only one problem and that too with ''enough'' theme. Is there anyway i can show the images ? If you know any site or something. 
The problem is that the body in which i write text has shrunk or i can say now there is greater margin on the left and right  of the text.

Comment: Yes you can upload image sin your question as described in this topic https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/218052 Also please share your site URL to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: [Here is the link](http://urootx.com) Have edited the question . Please have a look . Images - There is margin difference and that is the only problem.

Comment: I don't see the issue on your shared site and also don't see you are using any child theme on your site. Please advise.

Comment: Just take a screenshot and then i will change theme to child .

Comment: Do you want me to take screenshot? Please advise. Be more specific.

Comment: How would you see the difference ? If you take screenshot it would be better or you can just have alook at my edited question you will understand.

Comment: Here's how it is displaying for me https://ibb.co/nH3NrQ

Comment: Right, Now take one more look on the [website](http://urootx.com) or see the images i have posted in edited question !

Comment: Yes i saw the issue now and this is because you are loading stylesheet files incorrectly and multiple times as shown in this screenshot https://ibb.co/jSmmJ5 To resolve it just try once what i have said in my answer.

Comment: Made the change as per your answer but i guess problem is still there ! How do you see that log Can you tell me ?

Comment: Try above shared modified code.

Comment: Now it is working as expected. How ? Can you explain a bit .

Comment: Basically the code in the style.css file of you theme should overwrite the code in the base.css file but as the style.css file was loading before base.css file therefore the code was not overwriting. To resolve the issue i changed the code to load style.css file after base.css file.

Comment: In codex they haven't mentioned anything about base.css . And in css folder of paerent theme there are 10 more css files. What about those ? I mean only base.css file is concerned why ?
And where this line came -
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', 99 ); This 99 ?

Comment: base.css file is specific to your theme so is not mentioned on codex. 99 Is action priority to load files late. Regadding other 10 CSS files I have already told you in my above answer "You don't need to enqueue other parent theme CSS files if you are not changing them."

Comment: Now when i am trying to change the font family of body in style.css of Child Theme it is not taking place. But when i am doing same thing in editor - > customize -> additional css option in dashboard , then changes are happening . Any help or suggestions ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

about styles you need to specify a name for each style the cant be the same and its necessary if you are overwriting it in your child and you want the parent styles to come before overwriting.

so if you want to your parents `style.css` loads after your childs `style.css` you need to queue it in your `functions.php` file so add this in your child themes `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'enough_style'; // needs to be same as parent style

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles',100 ); //it will be queued after base.css and overwrites it
?>
```

i tested this code and it works well now. your `style.css` is ok and u dont need to change it.

Comment: What changes should i make ? I have already added the template you @vahid have shown. Do you mean that for every wp_enqueue_style function call i should use different name for first parameter ? Currently i have used 'styles'. Can i put any name that i want ?

Comment: @Desperado yes you can specify any name, and actually they has to be different.

Comment: I have edited code and also posted here ( edited the question ) . Have a look tell me what i am doing wrong ? Styling is still different.

Comment: you don't have to create all css files in the child theme and you only need `style.css` ,  you need to load css parents only if you are overwriting them, actually you don't even need `fuctions.php`.

Comment: @Desperado wait a few minutes and i will edit my answer

Comment: okay waiting !!

Comment: edited my answer @Desperado

Comment: $parent_style = 'enough_style'; // needs to be same as parent style . What does it mean 'enough_style' How to find what should be this string . Theme name is enough. @vahid

Comment: the string should be `enough_style`, 
I've found it in themes main `functions.php` just copy my code to your `functions.php` and it will work